# Git commit "fatal: unable to generate diffstat"

Tags: git, pycharm, github-for-windows

While attempting to commit a modified CSV file (12.4MB, ~164k lines), I received the titular error message. There's only 2 results in Google for that message: 1) the source code that throws it and 2) a dead link.

Any ideas? I'm working both from the Github-provided git shell, as well as from the git client within PyCharm.

I also cannot run a standard diff on that file from the command line, but I can from within PyCharm.

Answer (score 7):

I have experiment similar problem.

My solution was to commit with quiet option :
git commit -q

Comment: I was at first sceptical, but this truly works. Apparently git really just fails to generate something (i.e. the diffstat) which is only needed for display.